# WEB SCRAPING behind LOGIN(Authentication) in Python

Tags: python, web-scraping, beautifulsoup, python-requests, python-requests-html

```py
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import requests

# Start the session
session = requests.Session()

# Create the payload
payload = {'_username': '[USERNAME]', '_password': '[PASSWORD]'}

# Post the payload to the site to log in
s = session.post("https://github.com/login", data=payload)

# Navigate to the next page and scrape the data
s = session.get('https://github.com/[USERNAME]')

soup = BeautifulSoup(s.text, 'html.parser')
results = soup.find(class_='js-pinned-items-reorder-container')
job_elems = results.find_all(
    'div', class_='Box pinned-item-list-item d-flex p-3 width-full js-pinned-item-list-item public fork reorderable sortable-button-item')
for job_elem in job_elems:
    title_elem = job_elem.find('span', class_='repo')
    print(title_elem.text.strip())
```

It's not working out. Please Help.
in the above code the **"[USERNAME]"** and **"[PASSWORD]"** are the username and password of the github account respectively.

Comment: Use [Github's API](https://docs.github.com/en/free-pro-team@latest/rest).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try this code

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import requests


login = 'USERNAME'
password = 'PASSWORD'

headers = {'User-Agent': 'Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10_10_1) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/39.0.2171.95 Safari/537.36'}

data = {'login': login,
        'password': password, 'js-webauthn-support': 'supported', 'js-webauthn-iuvpaa-support': 'unsupported',
        'commit': 'Sign in'}

with requests.session() as sess:
    post_data = sess.get('https://github.com/login')
    html = BeautifulSoup(post_data.text, 'html.parser')
    
    #Update data
    data.update(timestamp_secret = html.find("input", {'name':'timestamp_secret'}).get('value'))
    data.update(authenticity_token= html.find("input", {'name':'authenticity_token'}).get('value'))
    data.update(timestamp = html.find("input", {'name':'timestamp'}).get('value'))
    #Login
    res = sess.post("https://github.com/session", data=data, headers=headers)
    
    #Check login
    res = sess.get('https://github.com/')
    try:
        username = BeautifulSoup(res.text, 'html.parser').find('meta', {'name': 'user-login'}).get('content')
    except:
        print ('Your username or password is incorrect')
    else:
        print ("You have successfully logged in as", username)
```

Comment: Thanks!, its working for github will the same work for other logins URLs?
like for any website which has a user Authentication?

Comment: you're welcome
No, login is different to another sites

Comment: exactly what i was looking for :)